# Mongo/Ruby undefined method `update' for Mongo::Collection

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am having an issue within stupid-simple piece of ruby/mongo code below:

```
require 'mongo'

client = Mongo::Client.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'], database: 'dbs')
items = client[:items].find('issues.category': 'general')

items.each do |item|
  item2 = item
  client[:items].update({ '_id': item['_id'] } , item2)
end
```

I get `undefined method "update" for #<Mongo::Collection:0x4544580 namespace=dbs.items> (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `update` method for the MongoDB ruby driver, there is either `update_one` or `update_many`.

In your case, it looks like you're trying to update all:

```
client[:items].update_many({ :id => item['_id'] }, item2)
```

See docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-tutorial/#ruby-driver-tutorial)

Comment: You are 100% right, this works, thanks.
But in this - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Tutorial#updating-documents-with-update tutorial I used there is only `update`method which confuses me a bit